# How to use Select and Order by in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

I'm trying to run the following query in Oracle SQL Developer, and it's not recognizing the right paren, plus I need to return only the first row.

```
SELECT 'PX'
FROM CME_NYMEX_FUTURES
    where SYM='NG' AND CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_MONTH = '6' and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_YEAR = '2013'
      and OPR_DATE=(select opr_date FROM CME_NYMEX_FUTURES where SYM='NG' and TYP='6' and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_MONTH = '6' 
      and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_YEAR = '2013' order by OPR_DATE desc) and TYP='6' 
ORDER BY CONTRACT_YEAR asc, CONTRACT_MONTH asc
```

When I try the following, the results are incorrect - I should be getting back a datapoint, and instead I'm getting 'PX' returned:

```
SELECT 'PX'
FROM CME_NYMEX_FUTURES
    where SYM='NG' AND CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_MONTH = '6' and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_YEAR = '2013'
      and OPR_DATE=(select opr_date FROM CME_NYMEX_FUTURES where SYM='NG' and TYP='6' and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_MONTH = '6' 
      and CME_NYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_YEAR = '2013' and ROWNUM =1) and TYP='6' 
ORDER BY CONTRACT_YEAR asc, CONTRACT_MONTH asc, OPR_DATE desc
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are selecting a constant (`PX`). It will always be returned when the query has results. You need to SELECT items from the result set like `CONTRACT_YEAR`, `CME_MYMEX_FUTURES.CONTRACT_MONTH` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to decipher your query, but what column is actually holding your datapoint?  you're getting PX back because you're putting a constant of 'PX' as part of the select reference, rather than turning a result.

Whatever column that you have in CME_NYMEX_FUTURES for your datapoint should be listed here, not 'PX'.  Let us know if I'm missing your point here.